# Regex-Expression for a logical Searchstring

Tags: regex

I want to program a Search. The main problem is to search for quoted Text and using + and minus for the Search.

I hoped there is a regex expression for searching for e.g.

```
var test = '"search test" searchword2 -searchword3';
```

Should result in

```
[0] = 'search test';
[1] = 'searchdword2';
[2] = '-searchword3';
```

Thank You

Edit:

Sry, but I want to have the first result without quotation marks. My Mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to split the string on whitespace, except if that whitespace is enclosed in quotes. Right?

In that case (and assuming you don't have to deal with escaped quotes within quoted strings), try

```
"[^"]*"|\S+
```

[See it on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/lL6eG2).

If there could be escaped quotes (`\"`) in your string, use

```
"(?:\\.|[^"])*"|\S+
```

[See it on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/zE9xD3).

Comment: Can you supply me with a solution without the quotation marks?
Thank you

Comment: Difficult - it seems you're using JavaScript, right? That regex flavor doesn't support lookbehind assertions that one would need for this job. Can't you remove the quotes in an extra step?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you just want a regex that will split the terms out you could use

```
("(\w|\s)+")|([-+]?(\w)+)
```

http://rubular.com/r/aOKs3nF7Fk

Although your question lacks clarity

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm you may want to try:

```
/"[\w ]+"| (?:-|\+)?\w+ ?/g
```